# getOptionLabel in material UI problems

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have a constant like this :

```
const Reference = [
  { label: "RF-100", year: "Test" },
  { label: "RF-200", year: "Test2" },
  { label: "RF-300", year: "Test3" },
];
```

and I have my Autocomplete in MUI like this :

```
export const Auto: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="Combox-demo"
      options={Reference}
      //getOptionLabel={(option) => `${option.name}`}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" prefix="RF" />}
    />
  );
};
```

I am trying to get my getOptionLabel to show label - year
so It will be RF-100 - Test (as an example)

When I use

```
getOptionLabel={(option) => `${option.label}`}
```

I get

> Property 'label' does not exist on type 'string | { label: string;
> year: string; }'. Property 'label' does not exist on type 'string'

Any ideas guys ?

Comment: Where is Typescript getting that type for the `getOptionLabel` function? It's because you accept type `string` for `getOptionLabel`, and a string has no such property called "label". You need to fix that type.

Comment: change it like this `getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}`

Comment: hi @monim - I am still getting the same error. I want to concatenate label and year together. but I am getting : Property 'label' does not exist on type 'string'

Comment: I have done it like this : getOptionLabel={(option) => option["year"] + " - " + option["label"]} - but I think that could be looked quite ugly..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Problem

You are seeing in the TypeScript error that the `option` in your callback might either be an option object **or** just a `string`:

```
string | { label: string; year: string; }
```

The reason for this is due to the "free solo" mode of the Autocomplete, where the user can enter any arbitrary text and is not limited to just the provided options.

The [docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/autocomplete/#props) for the `getOptionLabel` prop say:

> If used in free solo mode, it must accept both the type of the options and a string.

#### Solution

You have two choices on how to proceed.

1. You can check whether the option is a `string`.  If if is not, then it must have the type `{ label: string; year: string; }`.  This involves a check at runtime but it is safer -- if you were to enable free solo mode then nothing would break, as you are properly handling `string` and `object` values.

```
getOptionLabel={(option) => typeof option === "string" ? option : option.label}
```

2. If you are not using the `freeSolo` prop then you can make a type assertion.  This is essentially telling TypeScript "trust me".

```
getOptionLabel={(option) => (option as { label: string }).label}
```